# Add labels to Categorical Data in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I am trying to convert survey data on the marital status which look as follows:

```
df['d11104'].value_counts()

[1] Married        1    250507
[2] Single         2     99131
[4] Divorced       4     32817
[3] Widowed        3     24839
[5] Separated      5      8098
[-1] keine Angabe         2571
Name: d11104, dtype: int64
```

So far, I did `df['marstat'] = df['d11104'].cat.codes.astype('category')`, yielding

```
df['marstat'].value_counts()
1    250507
2     99131
4     32817
3     24839
5      8098
0      2571
Name: marstat, dtype: int64
```

Now, I'd like to add labels to the column`marstat`, such that the numerical values are maintained, i.e. I like to identify people by the condition `df['marstat'] == 1`, while at the same time being having labels `['Married','Single','Divorced','Widowed']` attached to this variable. How can this be done?

EDIT: Thanks to jpp's Answer, i simply created a new variable and defined the labels by hand:

```
df['marstat_lb'] = df['marstat'].map({1: 'Married', 2: 'Single', 3: 'Widowed', 4: 'Divorced', 5: 'Separated'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your result to a dataframe and include both the category code and name in the output.

A dictionary of category mapping can be extracted via enumerating the categories. Minimal example below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['M', 'M', 'S', 'D', 'W', 'M', 'M', 'S',
                         'S', 'S', 'M', 'W']}, dtype='category')

print(df.A.cat.categories)

# Index(['D', 'M', 'S', 'W'], dtype='object')

res = df.A.cat.codes.value_counts().to_frame('count')

cat_map = dict(enumerate(df.A.cat.categories))

res['A'] = res.index.map(cat_map.get)

print(res)

#    count  A
# 1      5  M
# 2      4  S
# 3      2  W
# 0      1  D
```

For example, you can access "M" by either `df['A'] == 'M'` *or* `df.index == 1`.

---

A more straightforward solution is just to use apply `value_counts` and then add an extra column for codes:

```
res = df.A.value_counts().to_frame('count').reset_index()

res['code'] = res['index'].cat.codes

  index  count  code
0     M      5     1
1     S      4     2
2     W      2     3
3     D      1     0
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I wasn't specific enough. I don't want to address items in the frequency table, but in the individual data. Slightly altering your approach, I tried: `df['marstat']=df['d11104'].cat.codes` and `labels = dict(enumerate(df['d11104'].cat.categories))` . However, `df['marstat_lb'] = df['marstat'].index.map(labels.get)` gives me `None` for every value of `df['marstat']` Is there no way to set a set of labels (maps (?) in python terminology) 'along' the categorical data? Coming from Stata, it is pretty common there.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do `df['marstat_lb'] = df['marstat'].map(labels)` in your example? Then you shouldn't get `None` ..